# moving from one csv worksheet to the next in a python script

Tags: python, excel, csv, applescript, worksheet

I've been using excel to create .csv workesheets that I'd like to parse using python. Each worksheet is named after a shop (e.g worksheet 1: "Waitrose", worksheet 2: "Tesco", worksheet 3: "Asda") and contains a list of products (column 1) and their associated prices (column 2). I've written a python script that can access a worksheet and turn the contents into a dictionary (see below) but am struggling to find a way to get the program to access the next worksheet in the workbook. I want to end up with as many dictionaries as worksheets. The csv module doesn't seem to be of much help and I can't find a current third party python 3-compatible module that deals with excel. I was thinking maybe applescript but am  not sure how I'd embed this in a python script

> waitrose = {'apples' : 25, 'oranges' : 45 etc}

any suggestions?

paul.

Comment: CSV files can only represent one table/worksheet, so I guess you exported your Excel file into multiple CSV files, one per worksheet. Then you will have to read each of these files in sequence.  What do you have so far?  Which file does your script read in?  Why don't you use the `csv` module for reading CSV?  Cannot you just use `os.listdir()` or `glob.glob()` to get all CSV files and use your code to read each of these in turn?

Comment: As Ferdinand Beyer already noticed CSV file represents only one worksheet. If I'm not wrong Excel warns you about that when you saving workbook to CSV. If you wouldn't work with multiple files then take a look on the modules that can handle workbooks in Excel formats. For this purpose you may try [python-xlsx](https://github.com/staale/python-xlsx). This module can access data in the .xlsx files with multiple worksheets and it is very easy to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each worksheet must be saved as a separate CSV.  Since you are already able to parse a single CSV I'll concentrate on handling the individual files.  Once you have a CSV for each Excel worksheet, you can iterate through each `.csv` file in a directory using the `glob` module.  With `glob.glob()` you can use wildcards in the path, so if you want just the `.csv` files in a directory use the `*.csv` wildcard.

```
import glob
import os

for csvFilename in glob.glob("C:\\path-to-folder-with-csv\\*.csv"):
    # csvFilename now contains the full path to the next CSV in the folder

    # This will give us the basename of the file without the extension
    worksheet = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(csvFilename)[0])

    if worksheet.lower() == "waitrose":
        # Parse Waitrose CSV...

    elif worksheet.lower() == "tesco":
        # Parse Tesco CSV...

    elif worksheet.lower() == "asda":
        # Parse Asda CSV...
```

Comment: I didn't realise that when saving a file created in excel as a .csv file you were in effect only saving the single sheet as the file, rather than the excel workbook. I change tack and use the approach you have suggested in your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used it but have you looked at the xlrd module?  It appears to handle reading regular Excel files including Worksheets.

https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html